# Reverse for '{{ feature.featurename }}' not found. '{{ feature.featurename }}' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, url, django-models, django-views

When I AM trying to load html page an error occur . that is **Reverse for ' {{ feature.featurename }} ' not found. ' {{ feature.featurename }} ' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

**home.html**

```
{% for feature in features_obj %}
<li class="nav-item px-3 px-md-2">
  <a class="nav-link active text-light" aria-current="page" href="{% url 
     '{{feature.featurename}}' %}">{{ feature.featurename }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
path('',views.home,name='home'),
path('tutorial',views.tutorial,name='tutorial'),
path('knowledge',views.knowledge,name='knowledge'),
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    logo_obj = websitename.objects.all()
    features_obj = features.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'logo_obj':logo_obj,'features_obj':features_obj})

def tutorial(request):
    return render(request,'tutorial.html')

def knowledge(request):
    return render(request,'knowledge.html')
```

**models.py**

```
class features(models.Model):
     featurename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     image = models.FileField(upload_to='')
     description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**value that i want to access**

```
featurename = tutorial , knowledg
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to (and can't) use `{{` inside `{%`. Try

```
{% url feature.featurename %}
```